# Set dynamic style for Checkbox in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd

Is it possible to set tick container's style `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` in Checkbox dynamically from JSX?

I can do it with CSS/LESS, but I need to set specific color based on data from API.

**Example:**

[image: I want to do something like this:].

Comment: Can i see the data from API?

Comment: Well, it gets from API just normal hexadecimal color, something like `#ff0000`.

Answer (score 3):

If the colors from API are completely unknown to you until the time of running, then there is no way to accomplish the task with Antd library. Because the class you need to update colors for (.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner) is nested inside the parent component , and can be changed only in your .less file. 
As you can see in Rafael's example, you can only control the colors of the parent (.ant-checkbox-wrapper) from .js file.

On the other hand, if you know there will always be, let's say "#1890FF", "#FA8072", and "#008100" colors, you just don't know in what order, you can easily change the colors dynamically, by creating your logic around CSS classes. Which means you can map through all your checkboxes and give the classNames based on the color you get from API (getColor function). In order to do so, in your .js file import the data from API and define getColor function:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Checkbox  } from "antd";

export default class ColoredCheckboxes extends PureComponent {
    getColor = color => {
        let checkboxClassName = "checkbox-green";
        if (color === "#FA8072") {
            checkboxClassName = "checkbox-orange"
        }
        if (color === "#1890FF") {
            checkboxClassName = "checkbox-blue"
        }
        return checkboxClassName;
    };

    render() {
        const dataFromAPI = [
            {
                key: "first",
                name: "First",
                color: "#008100",
            },
            {
                key: "second",
                name: "Second",
                color: "#FA8072",
            },
            {
                key: "third",
                name: "Third",
                color: "#1890FF",
            },
        ]
        return (
            <div>
                {dataFromAPI.map(item => (
                    <div key={item.key}>
                        <Checkbox className={this.getColor(item.color)}>
                            {item.name}
                        </Checkbox>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your .less file reassign the colors for ".ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner" class originally coming from Antd Library:

```
.checkbox-green {
    .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
        background-color: #008100;
        border-color: #008100;
    }
}
.checkbox-orange {
    .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
        background-color: #FA8072;
        border-color: #FA8072;
    }
}
.checkbox-blue {
    .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
        background-color: #1890FF;
        border-color: #1890FF;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You just styled it, something like

```
    <Checkbox 
       style={{ 
           backgroundColor: data.backgroundColor, 
           borderColor : data.borderColor 
       }} 
    />
```

Comment: In this case, style is not applied to checkbox, but to the whole container.

Comment: @JV You don't have any code samples. How can I answer question?